# Несколько вопросов по оптимизации spa на react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, spa

Я пишу spa приложение на react/redux. Мне нравится что переходы между разделами и рендеринг происходят очень быстро. 
Но у меня есть экраны с большим количеством данных, запросы я делаю в componentDidMount без участия redux, естественно запросы занимают какое-то время, приходится каждый раз показывать лоадер на странице, что не очень красиво.

Можно ли средствами redux как-то оптимизировать это? Например подгружать данные до того как страница отрендерится?

И сразу второй вопрос, у меня таких экранов с данными очень много, то есть если они все будут лежать в глобальном store, не отожрет ли это значительную часть памяти и не скажется ли на скорости работы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов

Comment: Так в redux то же самое будет происходить, чтобы получить данные нужно время и придётся показывать лоадер. Можно грузить страницу без ещё не поступивших из redux props, но это будет страница без информации или с заглушками вместо неё.

Comment: А вообще, такие заглушки делаются со стороны сервера. Идея состоит в создании ejs вида с полной (насколько возможно) копией страницы.